# C++ and PowerShell: std::cout weird spacing with ANSI colors

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-studio-code, std

I'm facing a weird issue with `std::cout`, ANSI color codes and PowerShell (integrated terminal in VS Code).

I have written a sample program that asks the user for string input. In the prompt I make use of ANSI color codes, so the default value (in case the user doesn't input anything) is displayed gray instead of white.

Running the executable works as intended the first time, but when running it a second time there's a weird spacing that disappears after the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
This issue persists until the code is compiled again.

I have noticed that when I leave out the ANSI color codes, this spacing also disappears. I'd still like to use colors though.

Please see below for sample code and images showing the output.

What causes this issue? Is there a different way of using colored `std::cout` output in C++?
Thanks a lot for your time.

#### Sample code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string input;

  std::cout << "Input: \x1b[37;2m(default value)\x1b[0m ";
  std::getline(std::cin, input);

  if(input.empty()) {
    input = "default value";
  }

  std::cout << input << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

#### Running the executable for the first time

[image: execution_after_first_time]

#### Running the executable thereafter

[image: execution_after_first_time]

#### Additional information

- OS: Windows 10
- Terminal: VS Code Integrated PowerShell
- C++ compiler: g++ 8.1.0

Comment: The "weird spacing" is because the console is not aware that the ANSI sequences are non-printing characters.  I'm not sure with PowerShell how to notify it of non-printing characters.  Normally for this kind of thing I use an ncurses based solution, but I'm not sure what the PowerShell analog is for ncurses.

Comment: [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.org/) would probably work fine to get away from those raw escapce sequences. Using such a library makes it a lot easier if you need to port your program to another platform too.

Comment: @Eljay PowerShell is a *shell* just like cmd, bash or zsh so it knows nothing about ANSI sequences. Only the *terminal* (conhost.exe or Windows terminal which PowerShell and cmd attach to, with the Unix analog being xterm, konsole, GNOME terminal...) cares about those escape sequences to format the text properly. So the thing here is ANSI sequence support in the VS Code terminal

Comment: I have tested this sample program on other computers of mine. It works everywhere as intended (colors work fine, no unwanted spacing), but not in my main workstation's VS Code integrated terminal. Interestingly enough, it does work in PowerShell when I open it by itself.

Comment: @wgumenyuk as I said, it's the issue of VS Code's terminal because PowerShell has no idea what ANSI code is. It simply passes the byte stream to the terminal, and since PowerShell will attach to conhost.exe by default you'll see proper colors because conhost is a terminal and it knows how to treat ANSI sequences. There are lots of issues related to this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/search?q=ansi+sequence&type=issues Check if your issue is really new and is a bug, then file a ticket there